# Syntax highlighting for entire hyperlink in .txt files for Vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I didn't quite find what I was looking for.

Is there a way to do syntax highlighting for the **entire** hyperlink in .txt files for Vim?

This is what I have so far

```
hi Hyperlink term=standout,bold ctermfg=Cyan
let m = matchadd("Hyperlink", "http://")
let m = matchadd("Hyperlink", "https://")
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this questions [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) or [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [amazing URL regexp](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-highlighturl/blob/0e9535b4e89325b027bcabc3ae7bb13cf086bee6/autoload/highlighturl.vim#L18) in [vim-highlighturl pligin](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-highlighturl).

I use a bit simpler regexp:

```
syntax match Hyperlink `\v<(((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet)://|(mailto|file|news|about|ed2k|irc|sip|magnet):)[^' \t<>"]+|(www|web|w3)[a-z0-9_-]*\.[a-z0-9._-]+\.[^' \t<>"]+)[a-z0-9/]`
```